# Handling Pledge (performance based) donation with Stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm working on a fundraiser app.

Users can create a fundraiser - with a donation category - pledges (performance-based) donations.

That means - if a school has a running event - parents (or any other person) can go to a participant's fundraiser page and donate x amount of money per unit (in this case meter)

for example, the parent can decide to donate $1 per meter. therefore, if the kid ran 50 meters, the total amount will be - 50$.

I want to know what will be the best way to handle this kind of donation using Stripe.
What we are doing now is:

1. Creating a customer (if doesnt exist already) so we can store the card for later use. creating setup intent - sending the client's secret from the back end to the front end.

- `let customer = stripe.customers.create(options)`
- `stripe.setupIntents.create({customer: customer.id ...})`

2. On the front end - A donor filling the amount per unit (1$ per meter) - the donor can tip the platform (percent of the total amount or flat)
3. The donor filling the card inside Stripe form.
4. On the back end - we are attaching the card to the customer, storing data on the db (amount, tip, customer id, intent id)
5. When the event is over - the user can close the fundraiser and charge all the cards based on the amount and units. for example - we have 10 kids, each kid has 5 donations, each donation is 1$ per meter, and each kid ran 50 meters.

- On the back end - we are looping through all the donations related to the fundraiser. creating a payment intent that automatically charged for each donation.

```
let donations = Donations.find({fundraiser: fundraiserId...})
donations.forEach((item)=>{
  stripe.paymentIntents.create(
        {
          payment_method: donation.payment_method,
          amount: donation.amount * participant.units + donation.tip,
          off_session: true,
          confirm: true,
          ...
        }
})
```

The issues we are facing:

1. Stripe rate limiter - allows us to do 100 calls in a second for live mode. that means we need to slow our loop with interval.
2. Catching errors and success - in order to catch errors and success we need to async await, stripe functions returning promise. the problem with await is that it slows down the loop alot - one solution will be to use webhook to catch all the reponses - the issue is the amount of requests from stripe - we will need also to think about a rate limiter - but in case of multiple users requesting donations charges we can end up with many many incoming requests from stripe.
3. To not let all the users to request payments at once (to prevent massive requests - and sending massive amount of requests to stripe) - we need to handle a queue system (so we will not exceed the limit by Stripe and we can handle incoming requests from stripe). what do you think can be a good queue system - should it be on a seperate server? - do you think there is a better solution?
4. what fo you think would be the best approach in general to achieve the pledges (performance based) donations system.

**I can share more code if needed. and im willing to answer any question to clear it out.

Comment: Are you already being rate limited? Or is this just a precautionary concern? 100 req/sec is a lot more than it sounds like. As you mentioned in point #2, doing async await for each call should slow down the loop. I'd be shocked if you're hitting rate limits as-is right now.